# List not displaying on the Datagrid

Tags: c#

I have a duration given in months. And a DatePicker which is the Initial date. And a AutocompleteBox where Months can be selected. The months selected means to Skip that month. 
I'm trying to populate a list of the months starting from initial date to end. 
So for Example:

Initial Date is February 1st 2013, Autocompletebox.SelectedItems = (6,7,8,9, 12) and the duration is 24 Months.

It'll produce => [2,3,4,5,10,11,1,2,3,4,5,10,11,1]

Currently this is what I have

```
for (int period = 1; period < Findper(); period++)
{
   DateIntervaList = new List<int>();
   bool MonthOccured = false;
   DateInterval _dateInterval = new DateInterval();
   foreach (string value in DateAutoCompleteBox.SelectedItems)
       {
       if (Int32.Parse(value) != InitialDate.SelectedDate.Value.Month)
            {
                DateIntervaList.Add(Int32.Parse(value));
            }
        }         

    }
    InitialDate.SelectedDate.Value.AddMonths(1);
}
```

I create the List below and set the item source in another function

```
public List<Int32> DateIntervaList { get; set; }
Grid.ItemsSource = DateIntervalList.ToList();
```

The trouble I currently have is the GridView is not displaying any numbers, It just show blank rows and if i can get help with that, would be great.

Comment: have you set AutogenerateRows property of Datagrid to true?

Comment: Looks like something you should be doing with a LINQ query instead of a `for` loop. BTW if this is WPF or any other XAML-based UI you should be using DataBinding too.

Comment: Are you using this with the MVVM pattern?

Comment: Grid.DataSource = DateIntervalList.ToList();

Comment: I know it doesnt match MVVM pattern, wasn't related to the question. May I ask how this would be done with a linq query instead? Definitely would be a viable answer.

Comment: @user3276954 did you try .DataSource instead of .ItemsSource?

Comment: Yes. Not the solution, Gridviews dont have a DataSource Method.